# Zonal statistics query

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, zonal-statistics

I have two rasters (Hyrdological Soil Group (HSG) and Land Cover) and i'm trying to find the average HSG for each land cover type. The HSG raster contains the values 2,3 and 4 and there are 23 different land cover types. I've tried using zonal statistics using the mean statistics type, but this results in mean values ranging from 2.58 to 3.47.

I would like just single numbers (i.e 2,3 or 4) for each land cover type, is there a way around this?

Comment: So are you saying that want median or majority instead of mean? Or that you want the mean rounded to the nearest integer? Either way, the steps are trivial. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/zonal-statistics.htm